# The conditional check 'template is boolean' failed. while using the ansible assertion module

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

Here's my playbook.

```
- name: "Verify if the 'template' boolean has been set ?"  
  assert:
    that:      
      - template is defined
      - template is boolean    
    fail_msg: "'template' must be defined and be present as a boolean"
```

and i got the below error message,

```
MSG:
The conditional check 'template is boolean' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: no test named 'boolean'. String: {% if template is boolean %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}
```

Executing the ansible command like  `anisble-playbook -i ip "{'template': true}" sample.yml`

How to do i fix this issue. without removing **template is boolean** parameter.

Comment: Should be closed as not-reproducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The parameter *-e, --extra-vars* is missing in your run-string

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i ip "{'template': true}" sample.yml
```

Because the first parameter without option is considered a *playbook* you should have seen the error message:

> ERROR! the playbook: {"template": true} could not be found

---

- The Jinja test [*boolean*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-tests.boolean) should always be available the same way the test [*defined*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-tests.defined) is. I can't reproduce the problem. The playbook below

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - assert:
        that:      
          - template is defined
          - template is boolean    
        fail_msg: template must be defined and type boolean
```

works as expected. The test will pass if the variable *template* is defined and boolean

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -e '{"template": true}' pb.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [assert] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => changed=false 
  msg: All assertions passed

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Otherwise, the play fails

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [assert] *********************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  assertion: template is defined
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: template must be defined and type boolean

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Sorry type mistake. I haven't mentioned -e option in the ansible command.  And whatever you have mentioned I tried and getting the same error                                                                        `ansible-playbook -e '{"template": true}' sample.yml

TASK [assert] 
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'template is boolean' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: no test named 'boolean'. String: {% if template is boolean %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}"}
`

Comment: I'm using the ansible 2.12.2 version.

Comment: There must be some namespace conflict in your configuration. First, you should try to change the name of the variable `template` to something else.

Comment: It's working. After upgrade the jinja2 module using pip command. Thanks